# How to use an <img> Tag in Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I have a tracking tag from adcloud. Now, if I can rely on js, calling it from my Flash app works just peachy. However, my boss would like that I send the same information when js is disabled.

I have been given a tracking pixel image:

```
<img src="https://a.adcloud.net/retargeting/?keywords=dpsmapp_ordered" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="">
```

How would I use/call this in my Flash app? The first thing that came to mind was to simply perform a `load(url)`, but that gave me a `401: Denied` error.

Comment: Use a navigateToUrl, although I think it has to be clicked by the user. So unless you have JS enabled I can't think of any other way to trakc without user clicks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way would be to load it using either `Loader` or `URLLoader`, but this requires that the people hosting the tracker have set up a crossdomain xml file on their server.

Something like this;

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
```

You don't even need to listen to the complete-event, since you won't be using the file itself.

EDIT:
Another solution might be to set up your own web service somewhere (using PHP or whatever), that have all the crossdomain files etc set up, which would download the tracking pixel. Then call that service from flash instead of directly accessing the tracker. You could also send on a referral URL to the service and make it "fake" the header.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. This doesn't work for me (401 Denied error), but I'll upvote because I think this answer will help people with a similar problem (:

Comment: Hmm. When I try to reach https://a.adcloud.net/crossdomain.xml, I get a 401 (it wants a username/password). It's possible it's being stopped there (it's the first place flash would look for the file).